# How to combine sfc objects from R package sf

Tags: r, sf

Using the R package `sf`, how does one combine `sfc` objects? For example, given the following code, how would one create a single `sfc` object `sfc12` that includes the geometries from both `sfc1` and `sfc2`? (`length(sfc12)` should be 2.)

```
library(sf)
pt1 = st_point(c(0,1))
pt2 = st_point(c(1,1))
sfc1 = st_sfc(pt1) # An sfc object
sfc2 = st_sfc(pt2) # Another sfc object
# sfc12 = ?
```

Some approaches that don't work:

```
sf_sfc(sfc1, sfc2) 
# Error in vapply(lst, class, rep("", 3)) : values must be length 3,
# but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 2

sfc1 + sfc2 # Seems to add the points coordinate-wise.
# Geometry set for 1 feature 
# geometry type:  POINT
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 2 xmax: 1 ymax: 2
# epsg (SRID):    NA
# proj4string:    NA
# POINT(1 2)

rbind(sfc1, sfc2)
# [,1]     
# sfc1 Numeric,2
# sfc2 Numeric,2
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use `c` like its a vector:

```
> (sfc12 = c(sfc1, sfc2))
Geometry set for 2 features 
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 1 xmax: 1 ymax: 1
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
POINT(0 1)
POINT(1 1)
```

And the length is 2:

```
> length(sfc12)
[1] 2
```

Comment: and how would you combine numerous sfc objects e.g. from a list of sfc objects?

Comment: did you solve it Bernd? I am also not finding a convenient way to do it.

Comment: @Marco if this is an issue for you and Bernd then start a new question with a reproducible example.

Comment: @Marco `do.call(c, list(sfc1, sfc2))` worked for me.

Comment: Combine a list of `sfc` objects using `Reduce(c, sfcs)` or `purrr::reduce(sfcs , c)`

Comment: You can strip a layer with `unlist(recursive=FALSE)` and wrap that in `sf::st_sfc()`, giving you the following.... `sf::st_sfc( unlist(sfc_list, recursive = FALSE) )`

Comment: Thanks. This answer worked for me.  Just use c(sfc1, sfc2).

Answer (score 11):

Drawing from @TimSalabim's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49013533/2152245), if your `sfc` objects are in the same CRS you can use

`do.call(rbind, list(sfc1, sfc2))`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to iterate over a large set of data

```
sfc_combined = st_sfc()

for(i in c(1:2))

{

sfc_combined = rbind(sfc_combined, st_as_sf(sfc[i]))

}
```

comes in handy when combining multiple sfc into one